# Simple javascript function not working as expected. Why?

Tags: javascript, nan, console.log

For some reason, no matter what I bind to the variable theNumber, I still get the console outputting the first console.log() inside of the numberCheck(). I expected this to output the second console.log(), but it refuses. I have tried many different syntactical changes. Maybe I just don't understand the expression !Number.isNaN(). I thought that this meant if the number is a number than its true, but I might be wrong.

Keep in mind, I'm new. I understand terminology so feel free to communicate with whatever words. But my javascript logic is subpar.

```
let theNumber = 'god'
function numberCheck(x) {
    if (!Number.isNaN(x)) {
        console.log('You picked a number')
    }
    else {
        console.log('why won't this log');
    }
}

numberCheck(theNumber)
numberCheck(12)
```

The output:

```
You picked a number
You picked a number
```

FIXED and Working as Expected:

```
let theNumber = 'god'
function numberCheck(x) {
    if (isNaN(x)) {
        console.log('You picked a number')
    }
    else {
        console.log('why wont this log');
    }
}

numberCheck(theNumber)
numberCheck(12)
```

The output:

```
why wont this log
You picked a number
```

Comment: We hate images!

Comment: oh... okay well then what should i use

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Generally try to include the applicable code in your question. Either just the code or a code snippet works.

Comment: When i complete the link provided. should i destroy this post and make a new one?

Comment: No, just edit the question's body

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN  I'm not sure you understand what that method is doing.  If you look at the documentation, lots of things return false for isNaN that are not numbers.  `NaN` is a special concept in javascript.

Comment: accepted edit. now I understand fully on what people will want in the future. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Your semicolons are in wrong place BTW, remember to put them at end. Also, you are not closing your strings properly either. Not what you asked for but just note it in order to avoid errors in the future. :)

Comment: Thank you @CillianCollins  lol just copy pasted too fast from atom :) but I’m not gonna pretend like I don’t make syntactical mistakes still . Fixed it in the post

Comment: Good, but still a mistake. No ';' after the console.log().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS NaN is a value that differs from a type to another, basically NaN for strings, NaN for ints etc, what that method is doing is checking if the passed value is a NaN of type Number.

Comment: I get it so basically the if conditional will always produce true because I’m converting the type to number? And therefore by asking if a number is a number,  well then yes it’s always true ?

Comment: Actually when you gave it 12 it returned false then you inverted it, 12 is a number but not NaN, and the string is neither NaN nor a Number, if you give 0/0 it will return true because that evaluate to NaN for obvious reasons, and it's of type Number

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the argument `x` to a number

```js
let theNumber = 'god'
function numberCheck(x) {
    if (!Number.isNaN(Number(x))) {
        console.log('You picked a number');
    } else {
        console.log('why won\'t this log');
    }
}

numberCheck(theNumber);
numberCheck(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "isNaN" function can be tricky sometimes (see this part of the documentation "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN").
Since it seems you want just verify if a variable is a number or not, you can make it that way:

```
var theNumber = 100;   
function numberCheck(x){   
  if(typeof x === 'number'){   
    console.log('Nice you picked a number');   
  }else{   
    console.log('It is not a number');   
  }   
}   
numberCheck(theNumber);
```

"typeof" function will return the type of the variable "x".

Comment: Yea, I think I just realized NaN is a bit more confusing than I thought. I went to the documentation of isNaN() and it said use Number.isNaN(). LoL imma stick to typeof from now on untill I better understand NaN in javascript.